# Send message between swim lanes in a flowchart

Tags: uml, flowchart

When designing flowchart models for my programing, I sometimes ask myself if I am drawing email communication between swim lanes the best way. Perhaps there are some who has better suggestions to describe the following process?

**A** wants a specific customer list from **B**. To do that, **A** has to send a request to **B** - it could be an email. **B** creates the list and sends it back to **A**.

**UPDATE**
My initial illustration wasn't UML so I try with this instead - ready for your comments:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is a perfect and overall used approach. Rather than using swim lanes, which are just graphical elements on the diagram, you should use ActivityPartitions (which are real UML elements) which you can classify with the actors in question.

Further you should use ActivityInitial (full circle) and ActivityFinal (hollow circle with large dot in center) to mark the start and end of your flow.

For more examples see [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html).

N.B. Just noticing this is tagged with Visio. Since Visio is a pure drawing tool you should consider using a real UML modeling tool instead.

P.S. I see that Geert removed the UML tag. So I may have been deceived by the question and thinking of this as being an UML activity diagram. So that's what my answer refers to. Anyhow, since flow charts are ancestors of activity diagrams this might help as well.

Comment: Thank you Thomas! I have updated my drawing as you suggested so it is UML – using another drawing tool than Visio. 
Good to get the right terms – that the swimlanes in fact are a notation for showing partitions.
Do you think it looks okay now or perhaps that there's a better way to illustrate the communication between the two partitions?

Comment: That looks just perfect :-)